# Jersey sets value of POJO to 0

Tags: java, jersey-2.0

I am using Jersey 2.x

I have following POJO class with setters and getters.

```
public class AccountObject {

private int accountNumber;
private int accountStatus;

//Getters and Setters

}
```

This is my method signature in Controller

```
    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces("application/json")
    public Response createAccount(AccountObject accountObject, @Context ContainerRequestContext requestContext) {

//

}
```

I am calling my API with the empty JSON body

```
{}
```

**Problem is : I am getting accountNumber and accoutStatus values as 0**

I have written some validation functions to check accountNumber and accountStatus , so because of this behaviour , my function is bypassed.

I am unable to understand how the values are assigned to value 0

Comment: Do you want it to be something else?

Comment: I was expecting it to be null. since I did not provided it in json

Comment: You can't have a primitive be null. Can you try using Integer instead of int?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it to be `null`, try using `Integer` instead of `int`. An `int` cannot be `null` because it is a primitive type, but an `Integer` can.'

docs: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html

Comment: Sir How can I perform `null` checks now , Eg : If I introduce `email` in my POJO and I did not pass `email` in my request then I check it through `String.valueOf(AccountDetails.getEmail).equalsIgnoreCase("null")`. But if I make accountNumber as Integer and try to check whether it is null, then it will throw null pointer exception.
Basically I want to validate whether the key is present or not in the request. How can I achieve this

Comment: Could you do `AccountDetails.getEmail() == null`?

Comment: Yes I can , I just checked it.

Comment: Cool! Did you have any other issues? If not can you please mark it solved?

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with Jersey but with Core Java & Jackson rules.

Jersey uses Jackson to handle **POJO based JSON binding support** as mentioned [here](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/media.html#d0e7650)

so you have to understand how Jackson works when it receives and Empty JSON like below,

```
import java.io.IOException;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;


public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException
    {

        String JSON = "{}";

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        AccountObject acObject = mapper.readValue(JSON, AccountObject.class);

        System.out.println(acObject.getAccountNumber()+" :"+acObject.getAccountStatus());


    }
}
```

You will see that Jackson creates an `AccountObject` with **default int primitive** value as zero ( as per core Java rules ) , since it doesn't find any value in Input JSON.

If you change field types to `Integer` then those values will become `null` as per Core Java default field rules.

`int` is not a reference type so it can't be assigned to `null` .

So you need to change your POJO as per your validation requirements or change your validation logic as per your POJO.

Just for the sake of completeness , dependencies as below ,

```
    <dependency>
     <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
     <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
     <version>2.8.9</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
     <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
     <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
     <version>2.8.9</version>
    </dependency>
```